# Can the python compiler optimize two consecutive function calls with identical arguments?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, compiler-optimization

In my code, I have a line like:

```
result = len([x for x in otherList if func(x) is not None and func(x).weekday == 3])
```

Written in a for loop, I would just define a variable like `fx = func(x)` and then use it twice. But I rather like the way my code is currently written, I am just concerned that since `func(x)` can be expensive, it will be evaluated twice. Is there some reasonably easy way to know whether the compiler would optimize such a statement and only evaluate the function once?

Comment: Can you initialize your variables with something simple to make this a running example?

Comment: I'd expect it would get called twice.  To not do that, the compiler (interpreter) would have to check that it has no side-effects.  Because if it *did* have side-effects, this could would make them happen twice (when it doesn't return None the first time).

Comment: use [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) and save function call inside a object and use that object again after `and`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some reasonably easy way to know whether the compiler would optimize such a statement and only evaluate the function once?

Yes, there is, you can look at the generated bytecode:

```
import dis

otherList = []
def func(x):
    pass

def main():
    result = len([x for x in otherList if func(x) is not None and func(x).weekday == 3])

print(dis.dis(main))
```

Output:

```
Disassembly of <code object <listcomp> at 0x000002AAC3C743A0, file "test.py", line 8>:
  8           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                34 (to 40)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (func)
             10 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 IS_OP                    1
             18 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             20 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (func)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 LOAD_ATTR                1 (weekday)
             28 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
             30 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             32 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        4
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             36 LIST_APPEND              2
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   40 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

As you can see, the function is called twice.

How should the interpreter know that the result will not change based on some global variable?

If the result of your function never changes for the same arguments, you could consider to cache it, e.g. by using lru_cache

As @sahasrara62 pointed out, you could also use [“the walrus operator”](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) to store the result of a function call within your expression.

Comment: Beautiful.. I did not know about this nice module. Thank you! And also to sahasrara62.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/) for that:

```
result = len([x for x in otherList if (out:=func(x)) is not None and out.weekday == 3])
```

Note that using `sum` might be more efficient if you only want the number of matches:

```
result = sum(1 for x in otherList if (out:=func(x)) is not None and out.weekday == 3)
```

Comment: That's interesting, why is sum more efficient? Is that because it never needs to construct the list itself and len() does not take generators as an argument?

Comment: @doublefelix Not sure, if you compare `len([x for x in range(1000000)])`, `sum(1 for x in range(1000000))`, and `len([1 for x in range(1000000)])`, the third one is the fastest. Summing also has a cost ;)

Comment: Hm interesting. Well either way it's better not to store x then. I wonder if those examples could be affected by some kind of optimization of the use of range()